# populate a treeview with xml file using c#

Tags: c#, xml, data-binding

Im using c#.net windows form application. I have an xml file that contains nodes. I need to populate a treeview with the nodes present in the xml file. Also avoid repeated node names. For this my idea is while populating the treeview, copy the node names into a list and there see if the node already exits. If it already exits, go to the next node else display it. 
List listOfNodes = new List();

listOfNodes.Add(xNode.Name.ToString());
 //if (!(listOfNodes.Contains(xNode.Name.ToString())))

I was trying with this. but Im unable to do. Please suggest me with a proper code.

Comment: I'm guessing you still get duplicates in your treeview?

Comment: ya. ur right. I came to know that we can use xelement instead of xdocument. please help if u can

Answer (score 1):

I suggest looking at some examples of binding xml to a [TreeView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.treeview.aspx) using [XmlDataProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.xmldataprovider.aspx) and [HierarchicalDataTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate.aspx). As the example in XmlDataProvider's documentation shows, the key to showing node name is to use `Path="Name"` instead of `XPath` in the binding.